# How to find the common values in a particular column in a particular table and display the intersected output

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Table

```
Roll  Class  Country  Rights  CountryAcc
1     x      IND      23      US
1     x1     IND      32      Ind
2     s      US       12      US
3     q      IRL      33      CA
4     a      PAK      12      PAK
4     e      PAK      12      IND
5     f      US       21      CA
5     g      US       31      PAK
6     h      US       21      BAN
```

I want to display only those `Rolls` whose `CountryAcc` is not in `US` or `CA`. For example: if `Roll` `1` has one `CountryAcc` in `US` then I don't want its other row with `CountryAcc` `Ind` and same goes with `Roll` `5` as it is having one row with `CountryAcc` as `CA`. So my final output would be:

```
Roll  Class  Country  Rights  CountryAcc
4     a      PAK      12      PAK
4     e      PAK      12      IND
6     h      US       21      BAN
```

I tried getting that output following way:

```
Home_Country = ['US', 'CA']

#First I saved two countries in a variable
Account_Other_Count = df.loc[~df.CountryAcc.isin(Home_Country)]
Account_Other_Count_Var = df.loc[~df.CountryAcc.isin(Home_Country)][['Roll']].values.ravel()

# Then I made two variables one with CountryAcc in US or CA and other variable with remaining and I got their Roll
Account_Home_Count = df.loc[df.CountryAcc.isin(Home_Country)]
Account_Home_Count_Var = df.loc[df.CountryAcc.isin(Home_Country)][['Roll']].values.ravel()

#Here I got the common Rolls
Common_ROLL = list(set(Account_Home_Count_Var).intersection(list(Account_Other_Count_Var)))
Final_Output = Account_Other_Count.loc[~Account_Other_Count.Roll.isin(Common_ROLL)]
```

Is there any better and more pandas or pythonic way to do it.

Comment: @EdChum can you help here if possible. Thanks

Comment: Please don't send personal requests for help I'm not your slave

Comment: Hey sorry, but that was harsh. @EdChum

Comment: Sorry but you've repeatedly pinged messages at users asking for help on some of your previous questions, as I've stated before SO is not a forum and not for you to make personal requests for help

Comment: @EdChum can we talk on some website. Can you help me or give me some idea. Sorry for disturbing you but I dont have friends who know PANDAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be

```
In [37]: df.ix[~df['Roll'].isin(df.ix[df['CountryAcc'].isin(['US', 'CA']), 'Roll'])]
Out[37]:
   Roll Class Country  Rights CountryAcc
4     4     a     PAK      12        PAK
5     4     e     PAK      12        IND
8     6     h      US      21        BAN
```

Comment: Thanks John. Can you please explain a bit if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
sortdata = df[~df['CountryAcc'].isin(['US', 'CA'])].sort(axis=0)
```

Comment: I am getting rolls which have two CountryAcc and one of them is US also. I am getting that row for eg: `1     x1     IND      32      Ind`